# Find an algebraic representation for $3$ pairwise relatively prime naturals.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a representation that shows $3$ different natural numbers are (pairwise) relatively prime in pairs.

The approach needed is algebraic.

To give an inkling as to what I mean by that, let us consider the problem of $3$ naturals s.t. the sum of any two is divided by the third.
Let the $3$ natural numbers be: $a,b,c$, so: 
$\exists l,m,n, \in \mathbb {N}$, s.t. 
$a+b=lc, b+c = ma, a+c = nb$. 
So, $c = \frac{a+b}{l}, a = \frac{c+b}{m}, b = \frac{a+c}{n}.$

Comment: Pairwise relatively prime or just $\gcd=1$ ?

Comment: @Peter I have edited for the missing info. It is pairwise relatively prime pairs.

Comment: Hint : Bezout's theorem

Comment: @Peter Please vet :: Say, $\exists l,m,n, \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $la+mb=n$. Similarly for other 2 equalities relating to the other two r.p. pairs. In nutshell, the 3rd number will not appear in the linear combination in such equalities for pairwise r.p. numbers.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime, then each of the equations $ma+nb=1 , oa+pc=1 , qb+rc=1$ has an integral solution.

Comment: Please see an extension of this problem at my post  : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634999/find-3-different-naturals-that-are-relatively-prime-pairs-such-that-the-sum-o.  Please guide.

Comment: I hoped that you will not mind helping in the stated post. It is not possible to extend this post to become that.